# Ansible - Registered variable missing iteration

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

So I have a situation I am trying to understand with Ansible and registering variables.

**Questions**:

1. When is the `regiter.results` actually created?  during the task or
   only after?
2. Why is `reg_nodes_ip|length = 3` but
   `reg_nodes_ip|length.results = 4`?

**Environment**:

```
ansible 2.10.5
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/etc/ansible/library/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Aug 24 2020, 17:57:11) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
```

- Ansible host: CentOS8 (latest patches)
- Targets: CentOS7 (latest patches)

**Playbook**:

```
- name: debug_nodes_ip_addresses
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_env']['SSH_CONNECTION'].split(' ')[2] }}"
  loop:  "{{ ansible_play_batch }}"
  run_once: true
  register: reg_debug_nodes_ip_addresses
#  failed_when: reg_debug_nodes_ip_addresses.results|length != ansible_play_batch|length

- name: debug_count
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ reg_debug_nodes_ip_addresses.results | length }}"
      - "{{ reg_debug_nodes_ip_addresses | length }}"
      - "{{ ansible_play_batch | length }}"
      - "{{ reg_debug_nodes_ip_addresses }}"
  run_once: true
```

**Results**:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    task path: /app/ansible/ansible_linux_playbooks/cassandra_cluster.yml:3
    Tuesday 23 February 2021  08:01:45 -0500 (0:00:01.845)       0:00:01.845 ******
    ok: [testserver11.local.net]
    ok: [testserver09.local.net]
    ok: [testserver08.local.net]
    ok: [testserver10.local.net]
    
    TASK [cassandra_cluster : debug_nodes_ip_addresses] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    task path: /app/ansible/ansible_linux_playbooks/roles/cassandra_cluster/tasks/configure_cassandra_cluster.yml:30
    Tuesday 23 February 2021  08:01:56 -0500 (0:00:05.568)       0:00:12.782 ******
    **ok: [testserver08.local.net] => (item=testserver08.local.net) => {
        "msg": "10.10.10.239"
    }
    ok: [testserver08.local.net] => (item=testserver09.local.net) => {
        "msg": "10.10.10.238"
    }
    ok: [testserver08.local.net] => (item=testserver10.local.net) => {
        "msg": "10.10.10.237"
    }
    ok: [testserver08.local.net] => (item=testserver11.local.net) => {
        "msg": "10.10.10.236"
    }**
    
    
    TASK [cassandra_cluster : debug_count] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    task path: /app/ansible/ansible_linux_playbooks/roles/cassandra_cluster/tasks/configure_cassandra_cluster.yml:38
    Tuesday 23 February 2021  08:02:14 -0500 (0:00:17.921)       0:00:30.704 ******
    **ok: [testserver08.local.net] => {
        "msg": [
            "4",
            "3",
            "4",
            {
                "changed": false,
                "msg": "All items completed",
                "results": [
                    {
                        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                        "changed": false,
                        "failed": false,
                        "item": "testserver08.local.net",
                        "msg": "10.10.10.239"
                    },
                    {
                        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                        "changed": false,
                        "failed": false,
                        "item": "testserver09.local.net",
                        "msg": "10.10.10.238"
                    },
                    {
                        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                        "changed": false,
                        "failed": false,
                        "item": "testserver10.local.net",
                        "msg": "10.10.10.237"
                    },
                    {
                        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                        "changed": false,
                        "failed": false,
                        "item": "testserver11.local.net",
                        "msg": "10.10.10.236"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Adding more detail to only suffice the site parser.  I am not sure exactly what details it is looking for but, this does not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- "{{ reg_debug_nodes_ip_addresses.results | length }}"
```

The `.results` attribute contains the results from your looping task.
It will have one item for each iteration of the loop, so since your
loop had four items, this will return `4`.

```
- "{{ reg_debug_nodes_ip_addresses | length }}"
```

`reg_debug_nodes_ip_addresses` is a dictionary, not a list. Calling
`length` on a dictionary returns the number of keys in the dictionary.
The `reg_debug_nodes_ip_address` variable has four keys:

- `changed`
- `msg`
- `result`

So this returns `3`.

```
- "{{ ansible_play_batch | length }}"
```

This is the "List of active hosts in the current play run limited by
the serial". You have four hosts involved in the current play, so this
returns `4`.

```
- "{{ reg_debug_nodes_ip_addresses }}"
```

This just dumps the contents of the variable. You can see here that,
as described earlier, that it's a dictionary with three keys.

---

The contents of `reg_debug_nodes_ip_addresses` is different
inside the loop (where it contains the result for a *single* task) and
after the loop has completed (when it will have a `results` key
containing the aggregate results).

That means you can't check `reg_debug_nodes_ip_addresses.results`
inside the loop (e.g., in your commented-out `failed_when` statement).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
Makes sense now.